# High frequency Insert into PostgreSQL, and the inserted data can't be selected until few minutes later?

Tags: c++, postgresql

I use the C API functions `PQprepare` and `PQexecPrepared` to insert data in PostgreSQL, the frequency is 10-100/s, with every insert statement contain 100 rows.

What confuses me is that the data I have just inserted can't be selected. About 1-3 minutes later I can select the data.

For example, I insert some data at 18:00, and in my C++ program the `PQresultStatus`'s return is success, and then I select them at the same time, the result is nothing. A few minutes later, I can select the data.

I want know is there a queue or other things in PostgreSQL, when I insert data with a high frequency.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities:

1. You don't commit the inserting transaction right away. That would be a bug in your application.
2. You query is running on a standby server, and the modifications haven't been applied there yet.